# "No operations defined in spec" Error while using RestEasy FrameWork with Swagger

Tags: resteasy, web.xml, jboss6.x, swagger-2.0, java-6

> I have implemented REST apis using RESTEASY framework
>   I am trying to implement swagger api documentation through web.xml
>   i am able to get index.html but error is thrown that can't read from file.
>   am I making mistake in making URL?
>   my web.xml is as follows:

```
   <servlet>
          <servlet-name>swagger-servlet</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
          <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>1.1.0</param-value>
          </init-param>
          <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://192.168.10.191:8080/restapi/myservice</param-value>
          </init-param>
    </servlet>
```